# Error creating trigger

Tags: sql, triggers

This is a simple trigger I'm trying to create:

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_item_id BEFORE INSERT ON products 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE max_id INTEGER;
SELECT MAX(item_id) INTO @max_id FROM products;
SET NEW.item_id = @max_id + 1;
END;
```

I tried it both on phpMyAdmin SQL window and mysql prompt and get the same error as below:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER add_item_id BEFORE INSERT ON products 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE max_id int;
SELECT MAX(item_id) INTO max_id FROM products;
SET NEW.item_id = max_id + 1;
END//
delimiter ;
```

Some notes:

- If you declare (local variable) max_id, use it. @max_id is a GLOBAL variable. Any @variable can be used without declaring it, but it stays with the session as long as the session lives.
- Your code is fine, you are just missing the delimiter changes. Without `delimiter //`, MySQL sees the CREATE TRIGGER statement ending at `..FROM PRODUCTS;`, which makes it invalid

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_item_id
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON products 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.item_id = 1 + ( SELECT MAX(item_id)
                          FROM products
                        ) ;
END;
```

---

Note: you can declare auto_incremented fields in almost all RDBMS.